# ASP.NET dynamic localization for English and one more language

Tags: asp.net, localization, dynamic-data

I'm creating a website template where the owner of the site will be able to choose a native language other than English and localize some content by themselves. Let me explain it better with the real situation right now: My site will have English and Turkish (my native language is Turkish, but THIS should be changeable and applied to any non-English language) versions of the main content titles, such as BLOG, PROJECTS, ABOUT, CONTACT etc, but number and name of these are completely dependent to the choice of the user, so I could open a new section named MySection, and it's title and it's native translation to Turkish will be stored in my DB (using EF). Also in my settings at the DB, the native language's code (in this case "tr") is stored. What is the most modular/organized way of sending the webpage content according to browser, just like this:

In DB, sections are organized this way (titles and their Turkish translations) (all these will be at arbitrary number and completely user created):

```
  Title     NativeTitle
  ---------------------
  BLOG      BLOG
  PROJECTS  PROJELER
  ABOUT     HAKKINDA
```

Also I have my native language setting (that I've created) setting as `tr` (which is up to the site owner and can be changed too). So, depending on the user's browsers preferred language setting, I want to show the Turkish content, and for all the other language preferences, including (obviously) English, I want to show the default English content. Localization for a specific language of static content is pretty straightforward with RESX files, but in my situation, I neither have static content nor a specific known native language, so all my data comes from the DB. I want to code this as less as possible and as declarative as possible. What is the best practice of doing this? Is checking the setting of the native language and the Current Culture in a page and if they are equal sending the native else sending the default title the only way? It WILL definitely work, but what if I want to extend it to other parts of the site? I don't want if's and else's everywhere around the site, I need some kind of a centralized string mapping system. What's the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the InitializeCulture ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture.aspx ) method in your base `Pag`e to dynamically load your localized content by checking the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` property ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture.aspx )

Comment: Obviously all of your Pages have to inherit from your PageBase class (which inherits from System.Web.UI.Page). You can ensure this by web.config (see PageBaseType attribute http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363.aspx)

Comment: Yes, this worked exactly that way with creating a custom Page class (with a little extra work).